# Question about event dispatching behavior in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I have a test python snippets:

py file:

```
from kivy.app import App
class tutorApp(App):

    def bn_pressed(self,button):
        print(button.text)
        return True

app = tutorApp()
app.load_kv('tutorial-3.kv')
app.run()
```

and kv file(tutorial-3.kv):

```
<Tb@Button>:
    on_touch_down:app.bn_pressed(self)


BoxLayout:
    Tb:
        text:'button1'
    Tb:
        text:'button2'
    Tb: 
        text:'button3'
```

When I pressed those three button from left to right, I got:

```
# press left
button3
button2
button1
# press middle
button3
button2
# press right
button3
```

and I change the line:

```
<Tb@Button>
```

to

```
<Tb@Lable>
```

and do the press again, I got:

```
# press left label
button3
button2
button1
# press middle label
button3
button2
button1
# press right label
button3
button2
button1
```

what is the cause of this differences? it is suppose to stop the event propagation when I renturn True in the event_handler, why it is keep get called?

thank for any help.

btw. If I change the event to on_press, everything just fine, the correct handler and only the correct handle is called when any of the three button was pressed.

Answer (score 1):

The label documentation states the propagation will stop if True is returned. I suggest a bug report. I see the same thing you do with this example.

https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.label.html

> on_touch_down(touch)
>
> bool If True, the dispatching of the touch event will stop. If False, the event will continue to be dispatched to the rest of the widget tree.

Answer (score 0):

It is the `on_touch_down` method that must return True to halt propagation. The `on_touch_down:` you use in kv doesn't replace this method, or any other python code, but instead just attaches to the `on_touch_down` event. That means you can e.g. write `on_touch_down:` more than once in the same kv rule and have all of the bindings still work.

Comment: Do you mean I have to overload the on_touch_down method of related widget in python script to change this behavior?